# ld: library not found for -lPods lang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode8

Getting the error While upgraded the code to xcode 8 and iOS sierra 10.12.1 and set deployment target to 8.0. Earlier it was working with xcode 7 and deployent target was 6.0. Can anybody face the same problem while upgrading to xcode 8

Comment: Are you using Pod? if yes then, have you tried installing pod again??

Comment: yes I am using pods, and I have reinstalled them again . still problem exist.

Comment: did you change your pod platform to ios 8 before you reinstall them again?
you should now use platform :ios, '8.0' in your Podfile

Comment: here is pod file 
platform :ios, '8.0'

workspace 'Project'
project 'Project/Converse.xcodeproj'

target 'Converse' do
 pod 'AFNetworking', '2.1.0'
 pod 'SDWebImage', '3.7.1'
 pod 'PonyDebugger', '0.4.5'
 pod 'SSZipArchive', '1.6.2'
end

Comment: Try to delete pods. Remove all search paths from build phase, delete derived data and then again install pod.